# indexOf("-") returning - 1 every time

Tags: javascript, string, parse-platform

```
var shortLocString = locationString;
console.log("Index of dash in '" + shortLocString + "': " + shortLocString.indexOf('-'));
```

prints this every time:

```
Index of dash in '325–333 Avenue C, New York, NY': -1
```

Why do I feel like this is some stupid thing I'm missing at the end of a long day?

Thanks for the help!

Mike

Comment: `-` is not found because you have a `–`,  `'–' !== '-'`

Comment: You got character `0x96` and check for character `0x2D`

Comment: It's http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm

Comment: @snwflk: nope, OP has a 3 byte character `0xE2 0x80 0x93`

Comment: That's idiotic, but it worked... I don't even know how you're supposed to type that kind of dash. That's what gets pulled from the apple maps  library, passed into Parse.com, then pulled back out

Comment: @Mike V: you just copy it (the whole address) from somewhere

Comment: MS Word auto-correct maybe.

Comment: @zerkms: you're right. must have had some conversion going on.

Comment: That's what gets pulled from the apple maps library on a reverse geocode for address, passed into Parse.com, then pulled back out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some sort of not-hyphen character in your string. I'm not sure which one; there are a bunch that look like that.

Comment: `'–'.charCodeAt(0) === 8211`

Comment: Looks like an en dash, then.

Answer (score 2):

There are many hyphen-like characters available.

If you type in `"-"`, it might not be the same as the character which is being put in the string you're testing.

If you have the string you want to test (ie: that one), an easy solution might be to copy the dash which exists inside of the string, paste it into your `.indexOf` and try again.

For a more-robust solution, get the Unicodes for all hyphens (include the actual minus sign), and if you're dealing with phone-numbers or serial-numbers which have to be formatted the same way, every time, then manually do a RegEx replace of any of those dashes, into the format you will use for your checks.

Also, be prepared for headaches with MS Word or other rich-text editors.
They will swap your `"` for fancy quotes in a heartbeat, and then all of your strings are broken.  They may also use different character-mappings for accents, et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

It's because there's more than one type of dash - you're checking for a hyphen, but the address contains an en dash.

```
console.log("Index of dash in '" + shortLocString + "': " + shortLocString.indexOf('\u2013'));
```

should print

```
Index of dash in '325–333 Avenue C, New York, NY': 3
```

If your addresses are likely to include em and/or en dashes you'll want to check for the characters \u2013 and \u2014